# Parse string into nested array of operands and operators

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am writing a parser in JavaScript that turns this:

```
"(1 + 2 - (4 - 3))"
```

into this:

```
[1, "+", 2, "-", [4, "-", 3]]
```

The code I currently have is :

```
function parse(string) {
    string = string.split(" ")
    string = string.replace(/(/g, [).replace(/)/g, ]) //This part does not work
}
```

How would I do this without using third-party tools such as parser generators and in the most efficient way?

Comment: Do you mean by the `[` an array? Because you if want a string, it will be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/USCZT/. If not, you probably need a regular expression for this.

Comment: By `[`, I do mean array. How would I use regex for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but this may give you a general idea of one method of doing this:

```
function parse(str) {
  var tokens = [];
  var chars = str.split('');
  var currToken, currChar;

  chars = sanitize(chars); // remove invalid chars and whitespace

  for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    currChar = chars[i];
    if (currChar === '(') {
      currToken = parse(chars.slice(i + 1).join('')); // recurse
      tokens.append(currToken);
      i += currToken.length + 1; // skip '(' and characters covered by currToken
    }
    else if (currChar === ')') { // note that this assumes there is always one ')' for every '('
      break; // base case, terminates recursion
    }
    else {
      tokens.append(currChar);
    }
  }

  return tokens;
}
```

I didn't write `sanitize`, but you can write that yourself. Note that the above function breaks if there isn't a matching close brace for each opening brace. You can put it through another function that validates or fixes the string beforehand though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
string = "(1 + 2 - (4 - 3))";
string = string.split(" ");
var newStr = [];
for (var i = 0;i < string.length; i++)
{
    string[i] = string[i].replace(/\(/g,'[').replace(/\)/g,']');
    newStr.push(string[i]);
}

alert(newStr);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/mz926/2/)

Comment: No, I am trying to replace `"["` with `[`, a bracket that indicates the start of an array.

Comment: @eax maybe I am missing what you are trying to do exactly. but check out the updated fiddle. Does that help you?